# How to select data from the table not exist in another table sql

Tags: sql

How to select data from the table not exist in another table sql. I've tried NOT IN and NOT EXIST methods. But it causes performance issues for large amount of data. Can anyone suggest a solution for this.?
Thanks in advance.

I’ve tried the following.

```
SELECT name 
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM table2 
     WHERE table1.name = table2.name)
```

And **NOT IN** Cases.
But performance issues while a for large number of data.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and the query you have tried.  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you sure that your subquery is working? Something is not right, where is table2 ?

Comment: `Select name from table2 minus.     select 
  name from table1;` -- let me know if it works..

Comment: @PM. Script updated. The subquery is working. But it will long time for large number of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your table `table1` and `table2` have index on their `name` column, so you can try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

May be id column existed, if not, use `t2.name` as a replacement for `t2.id`

Comment: this is great answer!

Comment: @XianShu . . . This should have no effect on performance.  It is just an alternative formulation of the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   yes, it has. subquery would query all rows of subtable, but `join` just try to find rows that `name` equaled. Of course, `name` shoud has `index` on it, then `join` would work with better performance.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM table2 
     WHERE table1.name = table2.name)
```

You want an index on `table2(name)`.